# how to add search view on custom recylerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

how to set data multiple data from volley and store it on Recyclerview that data are fetch from server in string [].

```
for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
            JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
            productCodes[i] = jo.getString(KEY_PC);
            skuDescriptions[i] = jo.getString(KEY_SD);
            productDescriptions[i] = jo.getString(KEY_PD);
            thumbnails[i] = jo.getString(KEY_TN);
            innnerqtys[i] = jo.getString(KEY_IQ);
            outerqtys[i] = jo.getString(KEY_OQ);
            stockqtys[i]= jo.getString(KEY_SQ);
            isstockqtys[i]= (jo.getString(KEY_IS));
            thumbnails_main[i] = jo.getString(KEY_TN_MAIN);
            thumbnails_small[i]= jo.getString(KEY_TN_SMALL);
            thumbnails_ori[i]= (jo.getString(KEY_TN_THUMB));
            HashMap<String, AndroidVersion> mapper = new HashMap();
            mapper.put("NS01", new AndroidVersion(productCodes[i]));

        }
```

Comment: https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo

Comment: as like above bus data filter from string []